# Зависимые списки или несколько АJAX запросов

Tags: php, jquery

```
 $('#selectTerritory').change(function(){
        var selectTerritory= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            // beforesend:(presend()),
            data: {Territory:selectTerritory},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#detale_sitis').html(data);
            }
        });

    });

       $('body').on('change', '#selectRayons',function () {
        var selectRayons = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            // beforesend:(presend()),
            data: {Rayons: selectRayons},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#detale').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Такая проблема: есть данные, полученные аякс запросом. Как их сохранить и использовать в селедующем аякс запросе?

Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Объяви переменную до запроса

`var selectTerritory;`

Comment: Быть может, ответ даже окажется верным, только в текущем виде он совершенно неподробный и непонятный. Объясните подробно (воспользовавшись кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/707189/edit)), как это поможет?